# Click to item details page not showing anything in React & ID undefined

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

Probably a very easy one for a seasoned React dev but basically I’m getting data from a JSON Object to display the on a “Releases” page. When a user clicks, just wanted to show the details of that release ID but I can’t seem to get anything to show. Just want to show the image. description and title for each release. Thanks.

Code from App.js

```
  const App = () => {
  
return (
    <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<About />} />
            <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
            <Route path='/artists' element={<Artists />} />
            <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
            <Route path='/releases' element={<Releases />} />
            <Route path='/release/*' element={<SingleRelease />} />
            <Route path='/artist/*' element={<SingleArtist />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>

  );
}


export default App
```

code from Releases.js

```
  const Release = () => {

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className="release">
        {releases.map((release, i) => (
          <div className="item" key={i}>
            <div className="title"> {release.title}</div>
            <Link to={`/release/${release.id}`}>
              <img className="image " src={release.imageURL} alt={release.name} />
            </Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

    const Wrapper = styled.div`
      .release {
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(330px, 1fr));
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .image {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    `
    
    export default Release
```

code from SingleRelease.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Release from '../components/Release';
import releases from "../data/releases.json";

function SingleRelease(props) {

  const { id } = useParams()
  console.log(id)


  return (
    <>
      <div>Single Release {id}</div>

    </>
  )
}

export default SingleRelease
```

code from Releases.json (Sample block)

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "imageURL": "./images/cloudbursts.jpg",
    "title": "Cloud Bursts",
    "artist": "Eric Shans",
    "description": "Mexico City based artist Eisenheim is back on 3Bridge with a killer EP called 'Archetypes'. It features 2 original tracks with remixes by Primordial Om and Anduaga.",
    "buy": "https://www.beatport.com/release/ardour/3096956",
    "stream": "https://open.spotify.com/album/5vNYmx4uNY5fIPrOCR0cUa?si=lwCXwLGtSn6g6ZNToPZKRQ"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "imageURL": "/images/archtypes.jpg",
    "title": "Archetypes",
    "description": "Mexico City based artist Eisenheim is back on 3Bridge with a killer EP called 'Archetypes'. It features 2 original tracks with remixes by Primordial Om and Anduaga.",
    "artist": "Eric Shans",
    "buy": "https://www.beatport.com/release/we-choose/1916121"
  },
]
```

Comment: <Route path='/release/:id' element={<SingleRelease />} />
try this

Comment: thanks! the ID is coming back but I just want to view the item details as well

Comment: Could you please provide a sandbox?

Comment: @Moath i can later, thanks

Comment: @Moath https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-yonath-ce9c9b just expand the nav to goto releases page and click on a release (broken image)

Comment: codesandbox is broken, app is not running

Comment: @Moath sorry, try now https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-fast-8n54ix

Comment: @erics15 it was a comparison type issue, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to show the details of that release id, if you have an api, fetch based on the id, but you have a json array ready you just use `array.find`.

Example

```
const releases = [
  {
    id: 0,
    imageURL: "./images/cloudbursts.jpg",
    title: "Cloud Bursts",
    artist: "Eric Shans",
    description:
      "Mexico City based artist Eisenheim is back on 3Bridge with a killer EP called 'Archetypes'. It features 2 original tracks with remixes by Primordial Om and Anduaga.",
    buy: "https://www.beatport.com/release/ardour/3096956",
    stream:
      "https://open.spotify.com/album/5vNYmx4uNY5fIPrOCR0cUa?si=lwCXwLGtSn6g6ZNToPZKRQ"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    imageURL: "/images/archtypes.jpg",
    title: "Archetypes",
    description:
      "Mexico City based artist Eisenheim is back on 3Bridge with a killer EP called 'Archetypes'. It features 2 original tracks with remixes by Primordial Om and Anduaga.",
    artist: "Eric Shans",
    buy: "https://www.beatport.com/release/we-choose/1916121"
  }
];

const Demo = (props) => {
  const id = 0;
  const release = releases.find((r) => r.id === id);

  return <div>{release ? JSON.stringify(release) : "Not found"}</div>;
};
```

This should show you the object, you can then render whatever you want based on the result in `release`

**Issue #2**

`r.id === id` compares `r.id of type number` to `id of type string`, which will result `false` due to the `===`. To fix this, you can do `const release = releases.find((r) => r.id === +id);` and that will match perfectly

Comment: thank you but coming back as 'not found'

Comment: Can you double check the id is valid is is in the releases array?

Comment: yes seems to be.

Comment: Thank you!  the sandbox is working but the app is not. So strange.